# I'm / I'll be eighteen soon

Tags: tense, present-tense, future-tense

Is it correct to use simple present in this sentence?

> I **'m** eighteen soon.

Or is only simple future tense possible?

> I **'ll be** eighteen soon.

Or maybe either? Is there any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jay said, you can use the simple future:

> I **will be** eighteen soon.

If you want to use *I am* you can use near future:

> I **am going to be** eighteen soon.

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about something that will happen in the future. Therefore, you should use the future tense: "I will be eighteen soon." If you are eighteen now, than you can use the present: "I am eighteen now."

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to make sure that the present tense is incorrect here because you can actually use the present in other languages: "J'ai bientôt 18 ans", "Ich bin bald 18" etc.